Early 2000s 3D sci fi action series on CN or Nickelodeon
This show was about a group of Power Rangers-esque fighters. They all had different colored suits that seemed mechanized. 
The only scene I can remember from the show is them fighting some villain who was determined to turn them into metal one at a time. One of them was turned into mostly metal before the villain was foiled.
If I remember correctly, the show was 3D animated and appeared on Cartoon Network or Nickelodeon.

After some more research and happenstance, I have found the show: Voltron: The Third Dimension
The show involves a group of multicolor heroes (the Voltron Force) fighting evil in space using mechanized suits made to look like lions.  The suits could come together to form a large humanoid fighting robot called Voltron.  
The episode in particular I was thinking about is Season 2, Episode 5, "The Hunter".  The Voltron Force is captured by Kolak the Hunter and made to undergo a process to turn them in bio-mechanical beings. IMDB for the episode here.
